# Does Notes app macOS Mojave auto-move checked off checklist items to bottom, like iOS 13?

Tags: macos, mac, mojave, notes.app, sort

The Notes app on iOS 13 offered to automatically move checked-off items in a checklist to the bottom.

Does the Mac Notes app offer that in Mojave or Catalina?

Comment: It doesn’t in Mojave.

Comment: @needlol Can you make an Answer of your Comment so that I can accept it. Also, if the feature does exist in Catalina, mention that too.

Comment: I can’t say how it is in Catalina for sure (but if I remember it right it has the feature) and only know the answer for Mojave for sure so I rather not “answer” it officially.